# The campaign field is missing from Lead layout in Lightning

Tags: lightning, leads, campaign

When creating a new lead in Lightning, we were able to select the related campaign.
This field is missing from Lightning. I see there is an idea for that: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CPmxQAG
but with knowing Ideas status, I don't think this will ever get populated (so does the status of this idea).

So, how can we achieve this behavior? but still, use the OOB campaign field on the lead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom 'campaign' look up field and add it to the lead page layout. Then set up  a process builder to assign leads to the campaign as campaign members on lead creation.

Answer (score 0):

The campaign look up field on Leads has always been something of a special case in Salesforce Classic - it's included as a convenience when you first create a Lead, but not shown thereafter. The idea being that you add the lead to further campaigns via the campaign history related list where there is an 'Add to Campaign' button. In lightning experience the campaign look up is hidden entirely and users are encouraged to work consistently from the Campaign history related list:

[image]

See: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005401&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1